# Для чего эти фигурные скобки?

Tags: c++

Нашёл пример кода на с++. Суть такова:

```
        void test()
        {
         ??{
            Int x;
         ??}
         ??{
            Int a;
         ??}
        }
```

Что за скобки без какого либо объявления ?

Comment: Вопросительные знаки, надеюсь, вы добавили? `Int` с большой буквы тоже так и написан в коде? А вообще, это просто выделение блока кода, области видимости. Там, где виден `a`, не виден `x`, например...

Comment: Вопросительными знаками пометил эти самые фигурные , которые не понял для чего тут нужны

Comment: Дело в том, что с двух вопросительных знаков начинаются (нынче не рекомендованные к употреблению) [*триграфы*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A1%D0%B8)), так что... Лучше свои замечания добавлять *как комментарии*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несколько команд в фигурных скобках образуют один блок. Например команда **if** имеет синтаксис

```
if ( условие )
  блок-правда
else
  блок-неправда
```

И чтобы выполнить несколько действий при каком-то условии их заключают в фигурные скобки.

```
if ( x != 0 ) {
    int tmp = x ;
    x *= x ;
    x *= tmp ;
  }
```

Этот блок воспринимается как одна команда. Внутри этого блока разрешается объявлять переменные и они имеют локальную область действия. Область жизни заканчивается после выхода работы за фигурные скобки. И если тип объекта имеет нетривиальный деструктор, то он тоже вызовется.

Без команд **if** или других фигурные скобки ограничивают просто блок команд. Которые могут иметь свои переменные, у которых время жизни ограничиваются начиная от объявления, до выхода работы из области этих фигурных скобок. Также разрешается, чтобы они имели одинаковое имя, так-как они в разных блоках.

```
{ Int x ; // вызовется конструктор x
} // вызовется деструктор x
{ Int y ; // вызовется конструктор y
} // вызовется деструктор y
```

Если эти объявления не заключать в фигурные скобки, то деструкторы будут вызваны только при завершении функции.

```
void test()
{ Int x ; // вызовется конструктор x
  Int y ; // вызовется конструктор y
} // вызовется деструктор y
  // вызовется деструктор x
```